# <apex:pageBlockSectionItem> may have no more than 2 child components.

Tags: visualforce-component, pageblocksection

After doing some changes to the view by adding apex:pageblocksection and apex:pageblocksectionitem i am getting the error as given below. Am i doing anything wrong here? Any suggestions please.

`<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` may have no more than 2 child components

```
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Input - Please enter selection Parameters</h3>
            <div>
                <apex:pageblocksection columns="4">
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" height="200px">
                            <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="2">Filters</th>
                                    </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Account Name:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtAccName"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Account Rating:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:selectList value="{!SelectRating}" size="1">
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!RatingList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                                        </apex:selectList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Partner Type</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:selectList value="{!SelectPartner}" size="1">
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!PartnerTypeList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                                        </apex:selectList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Account Number (SFDC):</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtSFDCAccNum"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>SAP Account Number:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtSAPAccNum"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>State Code:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtStateCode"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Postal Code:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtPostalCode"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Phone Number:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtPhoneNum"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Fax Number:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtFaxNum" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3" align="center">
                                    <apex:commandButton action="{!SearchAccount}" value="Search" id="btnSearch"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionItem>                            

                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem>                     
                        <table border="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2">Harmonize</th>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <!-- <apex:selectRadio value="{!harmonizeParam}" >
                                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="AccNum" itemlabel="Account Number"/>
                                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Addr" itemlabel="Address"/>
                                </apex:selectRadio>-->
                                Account Name: &nbsp;<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!AccNum}"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr height="45px">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                Address: &nbsp;<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!AccNum}"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="48px">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                Phone #: &nbsp;<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!AccNum}"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="48px">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                Fax #: &nbsp;<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!AccNum}"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Wrap it in an outputpanel SectionItem -> Outputpanel -> stuff

Comment: @Eric Would you like to add it as an answer?

Comment: @Eric. Thanks. i tried the approach which you suggested and it is working fine.

Comment: @mast0r -- Done

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wrap it in an outputpanel SectionItem -> Outputpanel -> stuff

```
<apex:pageblocksectionitem>
     <apex:outputpanel>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" height="200px">
                            <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="2">Filters</th>
                                    </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Account Name:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtAccName"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Account Rating:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:selectList value="{!SelectRating}" size="1">
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!RatingList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                                        </apex:selectList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Partner Type</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:selectList value="{!SelectPartner}" size="1">
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!PartnerTypeList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                                        </apex:selectList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Account Number (SFDC):</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtSFDCAccNum"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>SAP Account Number:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtSAPAccNum"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>State Code:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtStateCode"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Postal Code:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtPostalCode"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Phone Number:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtPhoneNum"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Fax Number:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:300px;" value="{!AccName}" id="txtFaxNum" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3" align="center">
                                    <apex:commandButton action="{!SearchAccount}" value="Search" id="btnSearch"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
</apex:outputpanel>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionItem>
```